# Specializing struct template using enable_if

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to create a template class, that will implement a callback with a different signature, depending on if it is instantiated with one type, or two.

```
struct NoIntermediate
{
};

template<typename R, typename I>
struct ParserCallbackSwitch
{
     using type = std::function<bool(const std::string &, R&, I&)>;
}

template<typename R, typename I = NoIntermediate>
class OtherClass
{
public:
    typedef ParserCallbackSwitch<R, I>::type ParserType;

}
```

Now I want to add code so that if I is not specified when instantiating 'OtherClass', that ParserCallbackSwitch would be:

```
template<typename R, typename I>
struct ParserCallbackSwitch
{
      using type = std::function<bool(const std::string &, R&)>;
}
```

Notice that in this case ParserCallbackSwitch::type is a function with only two parameters.

I wanted to be able to do the following:

```
OtherClass<int, float> p; // p::ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string &, int &, float &);
OtherClass<int> q;        // q::ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string &, int &);
```

I can't figure out how to partially specify `ParserCallbackSwitch` for the case when I is of type `NoIntermediate` (i.e. I is not specified)

SOLUTION: Based on response below. Here is the code I finally ended up using.

```
struct NoIntermediate {};

template<typename R, typename I = NoIntermediate>
struct ParserCallbackSwitch
{
    using type = std::function<bool(const std::string &, R&, I&)>;
};

template<typename R> 
struct ParserCallbackSwitch<R, NoIntermediate>
{
    using type = std::function<bool(const std::string &, R&)>;
};

template<typename R, typename I = NoIntermediate>
class OtherClass
{
   public:
   typedef ParserCallbackSwitch<R, I>::type ParserType;
}
```

Comment: maybe you want a [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So! You're not properly specializing a template. You're defining two unrelated class templates that happen to have the same name.

There are multiple ways to do what you propose. This one gives the least specialized template a parameter pack.

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... S>
struct OtherClass;

template<typename R, typename I>
struct OtherClass<R, I> {
    using ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string&, R&, I&)>;
};

template<typename R>
struct OtherClass<R> {
    using ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string&, R&)>;
};

int main(void) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<OtherClass<int, float>::ParserType,
                            std::function<bool(std::string&, int&,
                                                float&)>>(),
                "Something wrong here.");
    static_assert(std::is_same<OtherClass<int>::ParserType,
                            std::function<bool(std::string&, int&)>>(),
                "Hmmmmmm.");
    return 0;
}
```

Your idea of using a default type in a parameter also works, but your syntax was slightly off. Here's how that would look.

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename R, typename I = void>
struct OtherClass {
    using ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string&, R&, I&)>;
};

template<typename R>
struct OtherClass<R, void> {
    using ParserType = std::function<bool(std::string&, R&)>;
};

int main(void) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<OtherClass<int, float>::ParserType,
                            std::function<bool(std::string&, int&,
                                                float&)>>(),
                "Something wrong here.");
    static_assert(std::is_same<OtherClass<int>::ParserType,
                            std::function<bool(std::string&, int&)>>(),
                "Hmmmmmm.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close, but I can't use void because in another part of the code I use that as a parameter for a function. The second one works perfectly if I use a default of struct NoIntermediate {};

I'll put the code I finally ended up using above. Thanks!